# Approvers user tasks

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-server, workflow-activity

I have site in Sharepoint 2007 server. I am using the workflow to assign task to task list.
when task is assign to particular user at that time User is assigned in Approvers group.

The problem is that when Approvers user logged in he/she able to see all tasks in task list. I don't want to display others tasks in task list for Approvers user but admin is able to access All task and list down all tasks in task list.

How can I do this?